# How to add extra files into Python package using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to include non-python files into *whl* package but I am by no means able to do it. My project structure looks like this:

```
Libraries
└── CsZkusebniLib
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── CsZkusebniLib.py
    ├── changelog.md
    └── pyproject.toml
```

My `pyproject.toml` starts with

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

I am running command `python -m build -nw CsZkusebniLib` from `Libraries` folder. The *whl* the
n contains `CsZkusebniLib.py` but there is no `changelog.py` in it. I started to read docs (e.g. https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#including-data-files, https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html and https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and made **many** modifications,  e.g. into `pyproject.toml`, I added

```
[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
CsZkusebniLib = ["*.md"]
```

and added `MANIFEST.ini` containing

```
recursive-include CsZkusebniLib changelog.md
```

but my `changelog.md` still refuses to appear in *whl* package stubbornly.

What am I doing bad? Is my folder structure not compatibile with the tools? (But I've never read it should look in a certain way!)

NB. I can use `setup.cfg` instead of `pyproject.toml` if it helps but I did not try it yet.

Comment: Your project directory structure is bad from my point of view. Check this [doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html). I recommend the `src` layout. -- But it actually depends on what you want to do. If you really want to have only one [single top-level importable module](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#single-module-distribution) `CsZkusebniLib.py` (and no importable package at all), then your directory structure is fine except that you should remove the `__init__.py` file.